Terraform Issue after upgrading to 1.8.1
I have a Jenkins server that is running within a Docker container. I custom build the Jenkins image with Docker, Docker Compose and Terraform installed on it.
I run it locally on my Mac, here's the Dockerfile that configures the Jenkins server:
FROM jenkins/jenkins:latest

USER root

# Install dependencies
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
        apt-transport-https \
        ca-certificates \
        curl \
        gnupg \
        lsb-release \
        software-properties-common \
        awscli \
        python3 \
        python3-pip \
        python3-venv

# Install Docker using Docker convenience script
RUN curl -fsSL https://get.docker.com -o get-docker.sh && \
    sh get-docker.sh

# Add Jenkins user to Docker group
RUN usermod -aG docker jenkins

# Install Docker Compose
ENV DOCKER_COMPOSE_VERSION=1.29.0
RUN curl -L "https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/${DOCKER_COMPOSE_VERSION}/docker-compose-$(uname -s)-$(uname -m)" -o /usr/local/bin/docker-compose && \
    chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-compose

# Install Terraform
ENV TERRAFORM_VERSION=1.8.1
ENV ARCHITECTURE=arm
RUN curl -fsSL https://releases.hashicorp.com/terraform/${TERRAFORM_VERSION}/terraform_${TERRAFORM_VERSION}_linux_${ARCHITECTURE}.zip -o terraform.zip && \
    unzip terraform.zip -d /usr/local/bin && \
    rm terraform.zip

# Create and activate a virtual environment
RUN python3 -m venv /opt/venv
ENV PATH="/opt/venv/bin:$PATH"

# Install required Python libraries
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir requests boto3

USER root


When I run a Jenkins pipeline that eventually reaches a Terraform stage, I get this error:
+ terraform init
/var/jenkins_home/workspace/resume-app-pipeline/resume-app-iac@tmp/durable-fe149f76/script.sh.copy: 1: terraform: Exec format error

When I enter the Docker container that is running the Jenkins server and manually try to input a Terraform command, I get this error:
root@9ac5b490404d:/# terraform --version
bash: /usr/local/bin/terraform: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
root@9ac5b490404d:/# 

This started to happen yesterday after I upgraded to 1.8.1 from 1.7.5.
I have tried to chmod +x /usr/local/bin/terraform, no luck. Really not sure what is causing this.

Consider running terraform version command right after the installation in the Dockerfile, to see if Terraform was indeed installed.

Are you sure that the CPU architecture for the Jenkins image is ARM? There is also the arm64 zip file for terraform: terraform_1.8.1_linux_arm64.zip.

I'm pretty sure on a mac you want arm64 and not arm.

To make it more portable, you could as well use uname -p instead of hardcoding the architecture.

Seems that replacing the ENV variable that holds the architecture from arm to arm64 solved it. I did not change this anytime before now, and it was working perfectly. Perhaps Terraform changed their architecture definitions? Anyway, thank you all for replying. In addition, according to @MarkoE, I will now not hardcode the architecture.
